# mac: standalone hadoop SSH localhost connection refused

Tags: macos, hadoop, ssh, hdfs

I'm trying to set up two types of hadoop clusters: one standalone via SSH localhost and the other in aws ec2.

Both fail for similar issues: a connection refused error.

Here are some pictures of the issues: This is the result of ssh localhost

[image]

The next is: the failed run.

[image]

This is the relevenat portion of ~/.ssh/config

[image]

I can run hadoop, hdfs, yarn, and all the other commands.  But, when I actually type this and run it, it fails:[image]

Of note, I'm following this tutorial for the aws ec2 cluster, (this command is almost at the end).  https://awstip.com/setting-up-multi-node-apache-hadoop-cluster-on-aws-ec2-from-scratch-2e9caa6881bd

Which is failling on this command: `scp hadoop-env.sh core-site.xml hdfs-site.xml mapred-site.xml yarn-site.xml ubuntu@ec2-54-209-221-47.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/conf`

That's not my ec2 link; it's from the example, but that's where it's faiing with the same error as the 2nd and 4th pictures.

Comment: Please use text . Not pictures. We need more details, like did you actually **start** HDFS? What errors did `start-dfs` command return since it seems your HDFS isn't started? What exactly do you mean when you say you "can run" those commands? Running just `hdfs` doesn't do anything except print help output, it won't try to connect. And EMR would be a lot easier to use than setting up your own EC2

Comment: Please see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for reasons why formatted text is really important, vs images of text.

Comment: Thank you for the help, all.  I resolved the issue by removing everything from my core-site.xml and avoiding using ssh altogether, so it's working in standalone for now.

Comment: I tried to message you personally to thank you but couldn't.  All of my errors were about ssh being set up incorrectly.  You're right about the help output; I meant that typing hadoop and hdfs had output that indicated hadoop was installed correctly.  Many of the tutorials I found for creating a cluster for truely distributed computing mentioned ec2.  I'd love a non-aws option but have learned s3 and ec2 recently.